# XCode4: Project settings differs from Targets settings?

Tags: iphone, code-signing-certificate

I don't know the reason but this happens at times. I am setting bundle id correctly and also installing mobile provisioning profile correctly but sometimes build settings for Project doesn't detect my certificate automatically(when I select iPhone developer in signing) but it does for build settings of Targets! I don't understand how this could be possible? AFAIK automatically detection of certificate related to bundle id in plist file that correspond to set in certificate which is I am making sure they both matches! Could anyone think of any scenario where Project and Target differs in signing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Project and Target settings; I believe the reasoning here is that one Project can contain multiple Targets if needed. Its usually one in the general case, the Target for your main application.

Therefore, the Project Settings will be the big, overall settings which apply to ALL your targets and I believe you will be able to customize them for different targets if needed.

The general guideline I follow is, I always set the certificates and profiles etc in the Project Settings, then go to the Target settings to verify that they have been applied (sometimes they are not automatically applied); and if not, reapply them there. This always works out for me without a prob.

Comment: Thanks Madhumal! It works fine for me as well but why did they differs in first place? When I change bundle id in plist, corresponding certificate should automatically be selected in both the settings. But this happens for Active Targets settings but not for Project settings sometimes and it matches to some other certificate(this should never happen!). I have to select required certificate manually for project settings!

Comment: Afraid I dunno why this would happen :( Leave it to some quirkiness in XCode :) But yes, I share your pain.. this sort of thing does happen now and then, and thus, as a rule, I always double check both the Project and Target settings and choose the correct signing options if I change the bundle ID. Not a big deal when you get used to it :)

Comment: Right :) Anyway, I was just wondering if I am missing something!